# Will "circus peanuts" biodegrade, and how?

Tags: decomposition

I have a compost barrel, and it is currently staffed by black soldier fly larvae. They eat pretty much anything, which is very satisfying to observe. I put a handful of the candy known as "[circus peanuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circus_peanut)" in there, and they haven't touched them so far. As you can see following the link, the ingredients are:

> sugar, corn syrup, gelatin, pectin, soy protein, food coloring, and artificial flavor

I assume these things are biodegradable, being "food", but if my star decomposers won't eat them, then what will? What can I expect to happen to these items in the compost heap?

As a follow-up question, was this a bad idea? Should I take them out and throw them away, so they can rot in a landfill instead?

Comment: The lack of moisture in them is probably the main difficulty. You might try crushing one so that moisture from the rest of the compost can enter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time answered this question. I didn't do anything to the candies, but moisture eventually worked its way in. After a week or so, they were showing definite signs of breaking down. After two weeks, I couldn't see a trace of them!